# How to use PowerShell to delete specific messages from an MSMQ message queue

Tags: powershell, msmq

I'm trying to delete specific messages from an MSMQ message queue using PowerShell. I'm aware that several new cmdlets for managing MSMQ queues & messages were introduced in PowerShell 4+, but from what I can tell, these still don't help me achieve my goal of deleting specific messages.

What I'm trying to achieve is a simple script that connects to a specified queue, then loops through every message in that queue, looks for a specified search string in the message body, and then **MOVES** any matching messages to another queue on the same server. I have this working very nicely for searching messages, and can COPY any matching using using the Send method:

```
$source = new-object System.Messaging.MessageQueue($sourcequeuename)
$destination = new-object System.Messaging.MessageQueue($destinationqueuename)
$msgs = $source.GetAllMessages()
foreach ( $msg in $msgs )
{
    #Extra logic here - check message body for search string etc...
    $destination.Send($msg)
}
```

But - once copied, my only option to delete the original message from the source queue seems to be purging the **entire** source queue, which will delete all  other messages as well, which I don't want to do!

```
$source.Purge()
```

I thought I was onto something with the new (PowerShell 4+) 'Move-MsmqMessage' cmdlet...

```
Move-MsmqMessage -DestinationQueue $d -InputObject $q -Message $msg
```

But I'm struggling to get this to work - I'm unclear if I can pass it specific message objects to move. Can anyone give me a working example of using PowerShell (any version) to loop through messages in a queue and move specific messages using this Move-MsmqMessage cmdlet?

Comment: You can't move messages outside the queue. You can only create a new message using the contents of the original to send to a different queue and then delete the original. May sound pedantic but MSMQ has the concept of the destination queue being the final resting place for a message. There's an underlying mechanism of acks and timeouts for confirming delivery to a queue. If you could move a message then that mechanism would have to somehow keep track of that activity (across multiple machines!) and inform the original sender each time.

Comment: Move-MsmqMessage only affects messages inside the same queue by using subqueues. A queue can be divided into many subqueues but all messages are still effectively in the same queue.

Comment: Thanks John that makes things a lot clearer for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested but you should be able to delete the message using the [ReceiveById](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1a5xef17(v=vs.110).aspx) function:

```
foreach ( $msg in $msgs )
{
   #Extra logic here - check message body for search string etc...
   $source.ReceiveById($msg.Id, [timespan]::FromMinutes(1))
}
```

Comment: This worked! By then calling $destinationqueue.Send($msg) I get the effective move that I was after. Original message removed from the source queue, a copy appears on the destination queue. I tried calling the .Send before the ReceivebyId function, but the script kept hanging and then reported a timeout. I can't quite understand how I can copy a message after I've already received/removed the source, but I think it's because in my full script I load all the messages into $msgs = $q.GetAllMessages(), so the copy is using what's in the variable NOT the actual source message?

Comment: Yes, its probably use the message in the variable. But I have no clue why your got a timeout if you do it the otherway.

Answer (score 1):

The question and answer do not contain the full scripts used. Here's the full script I used to remove a single message from the queue, once I knew the Id of the message.

```
 [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Messaging") 
 $queuePath = "FormatName:DIRECT=OS:MachineName\private$\NameOfQueue" 
 $queue = New-Object System.Messaging.MessageQueue $queuePath 
 $poisonMessageId = "d53df8ba-3b6a-418b-ab27-198655534253\39996" 
 $queue.ReceiveById($poisonMessageId)
```

Btw, to find the message Id is easy, btw.
Go find the message in: 
Computer Management -> Services and Applications -> Message Queueing -> Private Queues. 
 Open up your private queue containing the message you want to get rid of 
Select 'Properties' and in the 'General' tab is the message id.

Answer (score 1):

Extended version of script from Jay Dubya with deletion by pattern

```
$StringToFind = "AMS1-COMET5"
$QueueName = "AMS1-COMET5"

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Messaging")
$queuePath = "FormatName:DIRECT=OS:"+ [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostName() + "\private$\" + $QueueName
$queue = New-Object System.Messaging.MessageQueue $queuePath 
$SrcQueue = Get-MsmqQueue($QueueName)
$Messages = $SrcQueue | Receive-MsmqQueue -Peek -Count 10000000
$Messages |foreach {
    if ($_.Label -match $StringToFind) {
        $_.Label
        $queue.ReceiveById($_.Id) 
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this will help me make an even more powerful script.